# error: cannot find symbol private final java.util.List<MyData> mydata

Tags: android, kotlin

I am facing the following compilation issue while trying to run my newly created kotlin project

```
error: cannot find symbol
private final java.util.List<MyData> myData= null;
```

Comment: Please post your code! And please not as an image!

Answer (score 0):

That's not the kotlin syntax. Try this.

```
private var myData:List? = null;
```